# Replace Database in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, database-design, entity-framework-4

I use asp.net mvc and using databasefirst entity framework for database connection.I created edmx file and .tt extension file .Now i need to change the database(i.e replace database 1 with database2).How can I do this? 
Note: I Dont want to update the database1,
 I need to replace database1 with database 2 and have the edmx file updated for database2)

Comment: It can be done, and it's fairly simple... but, gah! I don't remember the specifics.  I wrote/found a helper function a long time ago, used it a lot and hardly ever looked at it again.  (It's kinda late in my time zone anyway; I need to be sleeping).  If nobody answers by the time I look back at this I may be able to post an answer.

Comment: Help me soon after you getup :D

Comment: if the point isn't to make some sort of silo thing (one db per customer) then bot's and kirsten g's answer is right.  if you *do* want to change it dynamically, I'll have to post my code.  But it doesn't look like that's what you want (from my fresh eyes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the connection string in your web.config

Comment: now its working! I thought I need to update edmx file.How does this work without making any change in edmx? (though i use the copy of the original database)

Answer (score 0):

kirsten g's answer is right. Just change the name of your connection string in the web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="YourEntityName" connectionString="THIS IS WHERE YOUR GOING TO CHANGE YOUR CONNECTION STRING;Integrated Security=SSPI;user instance=True;App=EntityFramework';" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```